# Javascript Function Syntax incorrect output

Tags: javascript

New to coding and new to this website. I did try to search for the answer
to my question in the previously asked questions section but they all seemed way above my pay-grade. So, below is my code I'm using and my question is below it. (btw I'm using codeacademy to learn if this stuff looks really basic :/)

```js
var greeting = function(name)
{
    console.log("Great to see you," + " " + "name");
};

greeting("Matt");
```

My question, I cant figure out what i'm doing wrong (if anything). I was under
the impression that in the line:

```js
greeting("Matt");
```

it would populate the name I entered there and tether it together with
the other part of the string I declared in the "var" as shown below:

```
 "Great to see you, Matt"
```

Unfortunately it does not. It is merely printing to the console "Great to see you, name". I feel like I needed to declare something to recognize the input I put below but the example given as a guide doesn't do this and it prints out properly as "Great to see you, Emily" in the example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Additionally, I tried my best to format
this in the most readable way possible. If you have any tips for future questions and discussions it would be appreciated!

Comment: console.log("Great to see you," + " " + name);

Comment: Remove quotes to show the passed argument. "" are used to depict strings

Comment: You are printing string `"name"` instead of a variable! use `name` instead

Comment: You already know about strings (e.g. `"Matt"`). How should JavaScript know that if you use `"name"` you want to get the value of the *variable* `name` instead of the string `"name"`? It cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Your name is in `""`, So it is as text, not variable. Just remove the `""` around the name.

```js
var greeting = function(name)
{
    console.log("Great to see you," + " " + name);
};

greeting("Matt");
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to call name, which is a variable that stands for the string "Matt". Right now, you are calling the string "name". Get rid of the quotes!

On another note, you can just add the space to the end of the first string and not have the floating " ".

Answer (score 0):

remove the double quotes `""` in `name` variable in your `console.log()`. If you put a double quotes to it, it will be interpreted as `string`

```
var greeting = function(name)
    {
        console.log("Great to see you, " + name);
    };
```